# adding arguments to ftw's pointer function

Tags: c

I'm doing a recursive walk and found ftw to help me.

My program has to step through a directory and find files. For each files it has to populate a FILEMATCH struct. to do this the buildFileMatch function takes in char* filename and char* term. The function that ftw points to can only take its default arguments

```
(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
```

But I need to pass it a term.

I also need to edit variables out of its scope.

Would using static local variable help?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can do everything you need to do on each match within the function you pass to `ftw()` (and therefore don't need information about the matches elsewhere), you'll need to use a global variable.  Using a static local variable will allow you to retain information between matches, but still won't give you access to it from outside your callback function -- either to set an initial value not known at compile time, or to get the value after `ftw()` returns.